# How to check with boost::filesystem if a path is a creatable file?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-filesystem

I want to check if a `boost::filesystem::path` provided by a user is actually a file which is createable. Createable means: the directory in front of the filename exists.

```
std::string input = ~/some/dir/file.xyz

boost::filesystem::path path(input);

if (~/some/dir is a directory) // <-- How to get this?
  return true;
```

What's a solution with `boost::filesystem`? Or maybe there are better tools?

Comment: Just try to create it and catch the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) has added [`filesystem`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) to the standard. So, yeah you should use that. Prior to [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) I'd still go with something like: [`experimental/filesystem`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs)

---

Once you have `filesystem::path path` defined, you can use [`parent_path`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/parent_path) which:

> Returns the `path` to the parent directory

You can use this `path` in the [`filesystem::exists`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/exists) which:

> Checks if the given file status or `path` corresponds to an existing file or directory

So the condition in your `if`-statement should look something like this:

```
filesystem::exists(path.parent_path())
```